# Different Result Set While using Criteria vs just Create Query

Tags: eclipselink, jpa

**Manual Method without criteriaQuery**

I have used this code to get result set which contains of Thirdparty by using a left join with another table ThirdPartyHasOwner which has two primary keys and is a foreign key itself. Now the below code retrieves the **correct result data set**.

```
Query query = emManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM ThirdParty c LEFT JOIN ThirdPartyHasOwner b ON  b.id.third_party_Id = c.id WHERE b.id.ownerId=1");
List<ThirdParty> thirdParties = query.getResultList();
```

**With Criteria Builder and Criteria Query**

But When using with the criteria builder and Query **the result set gives a wrong dataset**. The code is given below So to check whether both above manual query and criteria query gives the same query I added Property `<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>` for which both the above code without criteria query and the below code with criteria query both gave the same query Both the code and console result are given below

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = emManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<ThirdParty> cq = cb.createQuery(ThirdParty.class);
    Root<ThirdParty> a = cq.from(ThirdParty.class);
    Join<ThirdParty, ThirdPartyHasOwner> b = a.join("thirdPartyHasOwners", JoinType.LEFT);

ParameterExpression<Integer> balance = cb.parameter(Integer.class);

Path<Integer> path = b.get("id").get("ownerId");

cq.where(cb.gt(path, balance));

cq.select(a);

TypedQuery<ThirdParty> queryS = emManager.createQuery(cq);

List<ThirdParty> results = queryS.setParameter(balance, 1).getResultList();
```

The Console result (The **first one** is for the **Criteria Query** and the **second one** is for the **manual method**)

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2017-01-04 06:42:44.026--ServerSession(514728045)--Connection(1288428548)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-3,5,main])--SELECT t1.Id, t1.ADDRESS, t1.CONTACTNO, t1.CREATEDDATE, t1.EMAIL, t1.NAME FROM third_party t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN third_party_has_owner t0 ON (t0.THIRD_PARTY_ID = t1.Id) WHERE (t0.owner_id > ?)
    bind => [1]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2017-01-04 06:48:26.109--ServerSession(514728045)--Connection(1288428548)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-3,5,main])--SELECT t1.Id, t1.ADDRESS, t1.CONTACTNO, t1.CREATEDDATE, t1.EMAIL, t1.NAME FROM third_party t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN third_party_has_owner t0 ON (t0.THIRD_PARTY_ID = t1.Id) WHERE (t0.owner_id = ?)
    bind => [1]
```

[result for both manual and criteria query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ofJl.png) (result variable has the wrong data which is the result of using criteria query and thirdparties variable has the correct data set which is the result of the manual method)

**Last but not least I am using `javax.persistence.persistence-api` which is eclipselink**

[This is the overview of the Database tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYzRj.png)

**Model Class For Third Party**

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the third_party database table.
 * 
 */
    @Entity
    @Table(name="third_party")
    @NamedQuery(name="ThirdParty.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM ThirdParty t")
    public class ThirdParty implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="Id")
        private int id;

        private String address;

        private String contactNo;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date createdDate;

        private String email;

        private String name;

        //bi-directional many-to-one association to ThirdPartyHasOwner
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="thirdParty")
        private List<ThirdPartyHasOwner> thirdPartyHasOwners;

        //bi-directional many-to-one association to ThirdSeatAllocation
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="thirdParty")
        private List<ThirdSeatAllocation> thirdSeatAllocations;

        public ThirdParty() {
        }

        public int getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return this.address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public String getContactNo() {
            return this.contactNo;
        }

        public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
            this.contactNo = contactNo;
        }

        public Date getCreatedDate() {
            return this.createdDate;
        }

        public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
            this.createdDate = createdDate;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public List<ThirdPartyHasOwner> getThirdPartyHasOwners() {
            return this.thirdPartyHasOwners;
        }

        public void setThirdPartyHasOwners(List<ThirdPartyHasOwner> thirdPartyHasOwners) {
            this.thirdPartyHasOwners = thirdPartyHasOwners;
        }

        public ThirdPartyHasOwner addThirdPartyHasOwner(ThirdPartyHasOwner thirdPartyHasOwner) {
            getThirdPartyHasOwners().add(thirdPartyHasOwner);
            thirdPartyHasOwner.setThirdParty(this);

            return thirdPartyHasOwner;
        }

        public ThirdPartyHasOwner removeThirdPartyHasOwner(ThirdPartyHasOwner thirdPartyHasOwner) {
            getThirdPartyHasOwners().remove(thirdPartyHasOwner);
            thirdPartyHasOwner.setThirdParty(null);

            return thirdPartyHasOwner;
        }

        public List<ThirdSeatAllocation> getThirdSeatAllocations() {
            return this.thirdSeatAllocations;
        }

        public void setThirdSeatAllocations(List<ThirdSeatAllocation> thirdSeatAllocations) {
            this.thirdSeatAllocations = thirdSeatAllocations;
        }

        public ThirdSeatAllocation addThirdSeatAllocation(ThirdSeatAllocation thirdSeatAllocation) {
            getThirdSeatAllocations().add(thirdSeatAllocation);
            thirdSeatAllocation.setThirdParty(this);

            return thirdSeatAllocation;
        }

        public ThirdSeatAllocation removeThirdSeatAllocation(ThirdSeatAllocation thirdSeatAllocation) {
            getThirdSeatAllocations().remove(thirdSeatAllocation);
            thirdSeatAllocation.setThirdParty(null);

            return thirdSeatAllocation;
        }

    }
```

**Model Class For Third Party has Owner**

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the third_party_has_owner database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="third_party_has_owner")
@NamedQuery(name="ThirdPartyHasOwner.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM ThirdPartyHasOwner t")
public class ThirdPartyHasOwner implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ThirdPartyHasOwnerPK id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdDate;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Owner
    @ManyToOne
    private Owner owner;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to ThirdParty
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="third_party_Id")
    private ThirdParty thirdParty;

    public ThirdPartyHasOwner() {
    }

    public ThirdPartyHasOwnerPK getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(ThirdPartyHasOwnerPK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return this.createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Owner getOwner() {
        return this.owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Owner owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public ThirdParty getThirdParty() {
        return this.thirdParty;
    }

    public void setThirdParty(ThirdParty thirdParty) {
        this.thirdParty = thirdParty;
    }

}
```

So Did I do something wrong with the criteria query or is it some weird bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the log was fine still I have used a different method which gives the different data set.

Before Code

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = emManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ThirdParty> cq = cb.createQuery(ThirdParty.class);
Root<ThirdParty> a = cq.from(ThirdParty.class);
Join<ThirdParty, ThirdPartyHasOwner> b = a.join("thirdPartyHasOwners", JoinType.LEFT);

ParameterExpression<Integer> balance = cb.parameter(Integer.class);

Path<Integer> path = b.get("id").get("ownerId");

cq.where(cb.gt(path, balance));

cq.select(a);

TypedQuery<ThirdParty> queryS = emManager.createQuery(cq);

List<ThirdParty> results = queryS.setParameter(balance, 1).getResultList();
```

After Code

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = emManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ThirdParty> cq = cb.createQuery(ThirdParty.class);
Root<ThirdParty> a = cq.from(ThirdParty.class);
Join<ThirdParty, ThirdPartyHasOwner> b = a.join("thirdPartyHasOwners", JoinType.LEFT);

ParameterExpression<Integer> balance = cb.parameter(Integer.class);

cq.where(cb.equal( b.get("id").get("ownerId"),balance));

cq.select(a);

TypedQuery<ThirdParty> queryS = emManager.createQuery(cq);

List<ThirdParty> results = queryS.setParameter(balance, 1).getResultList();
```

The code which is being changed is `cq.where(cb.gt(path, balance));` to `cq.where(cb.equal( b.get("id").get("ownerId"),balance));` for criteria builder equal is used here is equal to `Where b.owner_id = balance` balance is a parameter